# f-string preserve multiline indentation

Tags: python

I am generating C++ code from python:

```
import textwrap

cpp = textwrap.dedent(f"""
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {{

        a[i] *= 2;
        b[i] /= 4.5;

    }}
    """)

print(cpp)
```

This code provides the following output

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

    a[i] *= 2;
    b[i] /= 4.5;

}
```

When I try to insert loop body from the variable, indentation breaks

```
cpp_body = textwrap.dedent(f"""
    a[i] *= 2;
    b[i] /= 4.5;
    """)

cpp_loop = textwrap.dedent(
    f"""
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {{
        {cpp_body}
    }}
    """
)

print(cpp_loop)
```

The output is

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

a[i] *= 2;
b[i] /= 4.5;

    }
```

I understand why this happens. I am looking for a convenient solution how to achieve proper indent without manually counting/adjusting the number of spaces and tabs for each fragment. Is it possible to make with some function/library that will hide the complexity of re-indentation?

---

I understand that taking python indentation into account can make the task extremely difficult. This is why I use `textwrap.dedent`: it helps to canonicalize string no matter in what python scope it is located. For example, `cpp_body` will always contain text without spaces at the beginning of the lines. The problem reduces to the question of how to observe that there are 4 spaces before

```
    {cpp_body}
```

in the `cpp_loop` variable and add them in front of each line of `cpp_body` variable when it is substituted.

Comment: I'm afraid that simple string-formatting is not powerful enough for this. What you are looking for is closely related to Python's own off-side-rule ("significant whitespace") which isn't quite as trivial to handle as one might assume. You would have to track whitespace per line or per (nestable!) statement, neither of which string formatting has a concept of.

Comment: @khelwood Removing indent for ``cpp_body`` itself is correct. The "problem" is that only the first (blank) line of the ``{cpp_body}`` *insertion* uses the indent of the template, with any trailing lines ignoring it.

Comment: Since CPP blocks are well-defined without indentation, have you considered just going with the messy indentation (or none) and applying a regular CPP code formatted?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I tried to address the non-triviality of python whitespace parsing in the edit. Perfectionist in me can't agree to use messy indentation. This problem seems trivial enough to not use additional tools like code formatters.

Comment: A trivial solution which may or may not fit your usecase would be to use the `%` string operator rather than f-strings.

Comment: @m.raynal It seems that it has the same limitation as the f-string solution, no? If multi-line string is substituted, starting from the second line, spaces will not be added, so indent will be broken.

Comment: @Curious The difference is that string formatting templates can be parsed to find the indentation level, unlike f-strings.

Answer (score 1):

It's not particularly beautiful, but it works.

Note that this is explicitly *not* using an f-string, but re-implements a basic version of the replacement behavior.

It also only replaces stand-alone lines, like your example has, but it should not be too difficult to extend it to replace placeholders anywhere.

```
import re
import textwrap

cpp_body = textwrap.dedent(f"""
    a[i] *= 2;
    b[i] /= 4.5;
    """)

cpp_loop = textwrap.dedent(
    """
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {{
        {cpp_body}
    }}
    """
)

print(cpp_loop)

variables_names = filter(lambda var: not var.startswith('_'), dir())
variables_pattern = '^(\s+)\{(' + '|'.join(re.escape(var) for var in variables_names) + ')\}\s*$'
variables_expr = re.compile(variables_pattern, re.MULTILINE)
linestart_expr = re.compile('^', re.MULTILINE)


for match in variables_expr.finditer(cpp_loop):
    indent, var = match.groups()
    indented_block = linestart_expr.sub(indent, eval(var))
    cpp_loop = cpp_loop.replace('{' + var + '}', indented_block, 1)

print(cpp_loop)
```

prints

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {{
    {cpp_body}
}}


for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {{
        
    a[i] *= 2;
    b[i] /= 4.5;
    
}}
```

Also there are probably a few caveats due to the fact that I search for the matching region with regex, but then do an "optimistic" (i.e. unchecked) standard string replace of `{varname}`.

There is a small, but non-zero chance that the regex matched a different location than the standard string replace will consider. Feel free to implement that part more conservatively.